# Moving array items around

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my array:

```
[2555] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 1246
                    [post_id] => 2555
                    [meta_key] => event_date
                    [meta_value] => Sept 24th - 29th
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 1245
                    [post_id] => 2555
                    [meta_key] => _edit_last
                    [meta_value] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 1244
                    [post_id] => 2555
                    [meta_key] => _edit_lock
                    [meta_value] => 1252519100
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 1251
                    [post_id] => 2555
                    [meta_key] => articleimg
                    [meta_value] => /image1.jpg
                )

        )

    [2038] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 462
                    [post_id] => 2038
                    [meta_key] => articleimg
                    [meta_value] => /image2.jpg
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 463
                    [post_id] => 2038
                    [meta_key] => _edit_lock
                    [meta_value] => 1251846014
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 464
                    [post_id] => 2038
                    [meta_key] => _edit_last
                    [meta_value] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [meta_id] => 467
                    [post_id] => 2038
                    [meta_key] => event_date
                    [meta_value] => Sept 15
                )

        )
```

I'm trying to get this into an array that looks like:

```
[2555] (
    [event_date] => Sept 24th - 29th
    [articleimg] => /image1.jpg
)

 etc...
```

I've written some nasty foreach and for loops and my head is swimming.  Am I missing a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $objs) {
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($objs as $obj) {
        if ($obj->meta_key[0] !== '_') {
            $tmp[$obj->meta_key] = $obj->meta_value;
        }
    }
    $array[$key] = $tmp;
}
```

That will flatten the array of objects to an array of key/value pairs with the object’s *meta_key* value as the key and the object’s *meta_value* value as the value if the *meta_key*  value does not start with `_`.

Comment: Amazing.  I bow to you, master of the array.  Thanks.